# Reset counter after each item

Tags: enumerate, counters

How to reset the counter of equation numbering after each item in the enumerate environment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just want to do that in one enumerate just go

```
\item\setcounter{equation}{0} blah blah blah \begin{equation}....
```

If you want that to always happen go

```
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{equation}{enumi}
\makeatother
```